# Literature for $\mathbb{P}_k$ bubble enriched for finite elements

Tags: finite-element

I looking for literature  for $\mathbb{P}_k$ bubble enriched for finite elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In our paper [Finite element decomposition ... flow equations](http://dx.doi.org/10.1051/m2an/2015029) -- see my webpage http://janheiland.de/publications.html for a link to the postprint -- we have touched on such "bubble enriched" Finite Element spaces.

The sources we based on were

- V. Girault and P.-A. Raviart, *Finite Element Methods for Navier-Stokes Equations*. Springer-Verlag. Berlin (1986)
- C. Bernardi and G. Raugel, *Analysis of some finite elements for the Stokes problem*. Math. Comput. 44(1985) 71–79.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! By the way, do you know literature for galerkin method for quadratical and cubic triangular finite elements on 2D?

Comment: I would recommend Braess: *FINITE ELEMENTS:
Theory, Fast Solvers, and Applications in Elasticity Theory* (2007)